# Map SVN users to Redmine users

Tags: svn, redmine

We are starting to use Redmine as our task tracking tool and for some reason we can't have the same SVN and Redmine user logins. How can we map SVN user names to Redmine user names via configuration files or something else?

As all commits now are being performed by Anonymous, we can't track who was the committer for the revision.

Any ideas how we could fix this?

**ADD:**
In fact there is a paragraph in Redmine wiki about user mapping configuration, but it's empty now. You can find it at the bottom of http://redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineRepositories

Comment: Bit of a Freudian slip there saying "trac" and not "track" :P I think you know what the better ticket-management system is :)

Comment: Yep, I like it more, but for some purposes others liked Redmine for this project.

Comment: In fact there is some paragraph in Redmine wiki responsible for user mapping configuration, but it's empty now.
You can find it at the http://www.redmine.org/wiki/1/RedmineRepositories

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also in the project settings for repository there is on the lower right a link called users. That allows you to map users that have commits to the users in redmine. If the login name matches the svn author it does the match for you. This information is as of Redmine 0.9.1.stable

Answer (score 2):

While I know this only works for a windows environment, we decided to deploy an Active Directory instance, and use SSO for both our redmine and svn installations via apache.  I would imagine you should be able to do this using any ldap server.